# How to fetch image names from database and display them in react app

Tags: reactjs, image

The images are stored in the client/public/images folder. And the file name and extension is fetched from a mysql database. How do I write the src attribute of the img element to display the images.

```
<img src={`%PUBLIC_URL%/images/${portraitFile}`} alt='' />
```

this is not working

My project structure:

```
- public
   -images
      - portrait.jpg
- src
   - components
       - image viewer component
- App.js
```

Comment: Are you using a react app or next.js app or vitejs app?

Comment: I'm using react app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it guys. It was supposed to be:

```
<img src={`/images/${portraitFile}`} alt='Portrait' width='70%'/>
```

since every component is rendered in the `index.html` file, I should've had made the src structure according to the `index.html` file. That was it

Answer (score 2):

You are using wrong syntax as per CRA app. Use the following:

```
<img src={require("../images/${portraitFile}").default} alt="" />
```

Give the path to your images folder.

If the images are in public folder. you can write:

```
<img src={`../images/${portraitFile}`} alt='Portrait' />
```

Notice the backticks since you are using template literal syntax.

Comment: `<img src={require('../../public/images/${portraitFile}').default} alt='Portrait' />` I've done this since its in the public/images folder, but the console gives this error `Cannot find module './'`

Comment: In that case you can just write: 

<img src={`../images/${portraitFile}`} alt='Portrait' />

I have updated my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: I've got it. It was supposed to be ` <img src={'/images/${portraitFile}'} alt='Portrait' width='70%'/>`. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

If your project structure is like this:

```
- public
  - images
    - portrait.png
- src
  ...
  - components
  ...
  App.js
```

and you put your image tag inside App.js, you can source the image like this:

```
<img src={`../images/portrait.png}`} alt='' />
```

If you put your image inside your src directory:

```
- src
  - assets
    - images
      - portrait.png
  - components
  ...
  App.js
```

at the app you can import like this:

```js
import Logo from "./assets/images/logo192.png";
```

and render using the imported Logo:

```html
<img src={Logo} alt="" />
```

Comment: I edited the question and added my project structure. How should I write the src attribute